# Right way to update the state with arrays or object in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the array values from a callback function to the state value. I need to set the `setState` inside callback function.

The callback function will have the array of items. I am using class component to achieve this. On a click of that callback function I need to set the state with the array of values in `setState`.

I have achieved the same by using two ways but I am worried about the performance of the component and I see in some post that using the spread operator will not be ideal solution, instead need to use the push. I am confused which is the best method when the component grows.

I have added the code structure below. Can anybody can assist me what is the best way to update the state. Thanks in advance!

```js
//My Component
class myComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props); {
    this.state = {
      processingItems: []
    }

    //1st approach
    handleOnAddingItem(processingItem) => {
      this.setState({
        processingItems: [...processingItem]
      })
    }

    //2nd Approach
    items = this.state.processingItems;
    items.push(processingItem)
    this.setState({
      processingItems: items
    })

    //3rd Approach
    handleOnAddingItem(processingItem) => {
      this.setState({ ...processingItem
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

React [new docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#adding-to-an-array) suggests spread operator and [avoid push pop](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#updating-arrays-without-mutation) operations

```
this.setState( // Replace the state
  processingItems: [ // with a new array
    ...processingItems, // that contains all the old items
    { id: nextId++, ...newItem } // and one new item at the end
  ]
);
```

and [copy the objects](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state#copying-objects-with-the-spread-syntax) in new state